# Localizing "Restore column order" text in xul column picker

Tags: xml, firefox, plugins, localization, xul

When a [tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/tree#a-enableColumnDrag) has the column dragging feature enabled(`enableColumnDrag`), the column picker has "Restore column order" menu item. How can I localize `Restore column order` text?

[image]

Comment: tree.columns.restoreNaturalOrder()

Comment: @linguini Thanks for the comment, how can I use that for localization?

Comment: I guess you know, there are 2 things, restore column order & localization. To localize any string format in XUL, there is an example in link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Localizing_an_extension#Localizing_strings_in_JavaScript_code

Comment: @linguini I know how localize strings that I add to a XUL component, the issue is that "Restore column order" string is add to menu automatically, and I have no entity for that is the XUL file.

Comment: Is it possible to post your code, here at SO?